# Click function with class to work solely for the current selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am having some difficulties getting a click function to work the way I am intending. When the user click the arrow next to the catalog name, `subViewBoxExpand` should appear for only that specific selection.

Does anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

```js
$('.arrow').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).next('.subViewBoxExpand'),
    t = $(this).addClass('active');
  i.toggleClass('active', !0).slideToggle(500).find('.subViewBoxExpand').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500) + t, $('.subViewBoxExpand').not(i, t).slideUp(800).prev().removeClass('active');
  //$('.subViewBoxExpand').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.subViewBoxExpand {
  display: none;
}

.subViewBoxExpand.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalogSubViewBox">
  <span class="catalogSubViewBoxTitle">Catalog A</span><span class="arrow"> ></span>
  <div id="totalProfileViews"></div>
  <div class="subViewBoxExpand">
    <p>You did it!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="catalogSubViewBox">
  <span class="catalogSubViewBoxTitle">Catalog B</span><span class="arrow"> ></span>
  <div id="totalFastViews"></div>
  <div class="subViewBoxExpand">
    <p>You did it!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and combine with [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `selected/clicked` element and its corresponding view box.

Note: the view box is not next to the clicked element

sample : `$(this).closest('.catalogSubViewBox').find('.subViewBoxExpand')`

UPDATE: Remove the class active that is also being toggled in view

```js
$('.arrow').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).closest('.catalogSubViewBox').find('.subViewBoxExpand'),
    t = $(this).addClass('active');
  i.slideToggle(500).find('.subViewBoxExpand').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500) + t, $('.subViewBoxExpand').not(i).slideUp(800).prev().prev().removeClass('active');
  //$('.subViewBoxExpand').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.subViewBoxExpand {
  display: none;
}

.subViewBoxExpand.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalogSubViewBox">
  <span class="catalogSubViewBoxTitle">Catalog A</span><span class="arrow"> ></span>
  <div id="totalProfileViews"></div>
  <div class="subViewBoxExpand">
    <p>You did it!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="catalogSubViewBox">
  <span class="catalogSubViewBoxTitle">Catalog B</span><span class="arrow"> ></span>
  <div id="totalFastViews"></div>
  <div class="subViewBoxExpand">
    <p>You did it!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea why the box is opening and closing immediately on the first click?

Comment: check the slide up in the chain

Comment: Hmm.. I tried removing the `t` variable in this not. Didn't help. `.not(i, t)`

Comment: @Paul remove the addClass active that is also toggled check demo above